# 403 AuthFailureError in Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I am having a very strange situation. I have a running script that makes JsonObjectRequest using Volley Singletone. The script has been working perfectly in domain example1.com. Recently I bought example2.com and hosted in the same hosting account. And when I copy all the php files as it is in the second domain, I am getting error "BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403".

So, I have exactly same php files called using JsonObjectRequest and Volley Singletone working in example1.com, but not in example2.com. I have check the permission of the files in both domain, they are exactly same (644) and there is no htaccess in either of the domain.

I am stuck and don't understand what else I should check?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you share the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with your server side php script - You can first try to test POST requests using some tool before implementing in your Android application:

If I performed a simple POST request (just using browser not Android) to your provided link I get following error:

**403: Forbidden**

> 403 Forbidden
>
> ## Forbidden
>
> You
>   don't have permission to access /mylibman_4_5.php on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
>
> ---
>
> Apache
>   Server at mylibrarymanager.com Port 80

Comment: Please check the following link it is not working with Volley but i am getting response from postman in get and post both methods :-http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&per_page=2&nojsoncallback=2&format=json&tags=delhi&api_key=6d6990e75d32280496e8b7d9e7ed4982&page=2