# How to disable returning volley network error?

Tags: android, android-volley

Here is my code to ignore errors:

```
new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError ignored) {
                    //nothing
                }
            });
```

But still it returns `403` error

```
E/Volley: [934] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for http://myawesome.site/login
E/Volley: [934] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for http://myawesome.site/login
```

**Another problem is**: above error shows twice in one call. It ignores `DefaultRetryPolicy` set to `0`

Expecting your help.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35238324/403-authfailureerror-in-volley?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

To stop logging network activity, call the `DevicePolicyManager` method `setNetworkLoggingEnabled()` and pass false as the enabled argument.

Your DPC can call `isNetworkLoggingEnabled()` to check if network activity is currently logged.

reference link :https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/logging.html

check this section : Enable network logging.

Comment: As you said, it will totally stop logging network activity. What I needed is a solution for this function only.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve problem by changing the method name. previously i am try to calling web service with POST method and I have changed to GET method then my problem solved. Try this solution by changing request method.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "YOUR_WEBSERVICE_URL",
new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response){}
},
new Response.ErrorListener() {
     @Override
     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {}
}) {

@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams()
{
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

    return params;
}
};
stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new 
DefaultRetryPolicy(60000,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, 
DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the server-side script accepts only `post` method.